# A comma before "because" in a sentence like "This effect happens(,) because of this cause."

Tags: punctuation, commas

In this sentence, should there be a comma before because:

> A file was excluded because it cannot be updated.

Part of me thinks cause and effect should have a comma.

> This effect happens, because of this cause.

However, this would also be a defining clause.  See: [Comma before "because"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4605/comma-before-because)

Comment: I can see no reason that justifies a comma here. If you were writing for a newsreader and you particularly wanted a pause after excluded, you might use some device such as a comma or hyphen. But grammatically it's redundant.

Comment: @RonaldSole What about an If ... then sentence?  If you do jump too high, you'll break your leg.

Comment: I would use a comma there because it makes the sense clearer.  Although there are lots of rules regarding comma use (as in: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma) there are often contexts where they are optional and it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: A comma is only necessary to interrupt a flow when you don't want a flow.

Comment: The part of you that thinks cause and effect should have a comma reminds me of the stand-up comedy routine of Tennessee comedian Nate Bargatze where he talks about the left brain and the right brain.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxw5rEzgp6A

Comment: The example is artificial because typically the cause and effect will be a lot longer, and therefore a comma may be justified. If you just want to say "disease happens because microbes exist" you don't need a comma, but longer sentences might benefit from one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most style books would qualify the comma as optional in this case. Leaving it out would not result in ambiguity, nor would the comma result in undue separation of main clause from subordinate clause. In short, the comma makes no difference. So write it if you want place extra emphasis on the main clause as an independent statement (not a formal term), or omit it at your convenience.

Comment: What about the cause and effect aspect?  Does that count for anything?

Comment: @GC_: Could you explain what you mean a little bit more? Yes, *because* indicates a cause or reason.

Comment: I thought one of my teachers insisted sentences like, "Blah blah blah happened, because blah blah blah," always requires a comma before the because.

Comment: I am not a grammar expert, so your probably right.

Answer (score 0):

The comma changes the thrust of the sentence. If you write, without a comma, *File A was excluded because it cannot be updated* your sentence is giving the reason why file A was excluded. If you are not explicitly told, you can deduce that file A was excluded, but that is not what the sentence is directly telling you.

If you write, with a comma, *File A was excluded, because it cannot be updated* your sentence is saying that file A was excluded, and giving the reason as a less important fact.

A paragraph like

> *Files A, B, and C were excluded. File A was excluded because it cannot be updated.*

makes perfect sense; the first sentence tells us that the files were excluded and the second sentence gives the reason that file A was excluded. Adding the comma, like

> *Files A, B, and C were excluded. File A was excluded, because it cannot be updated.*

tells the reader twice that file A was excluded.